# Trouble with Building Electron.js Project with Vite and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, build, electron, vite, electron-forge

I’m working on an Electron.js project with TypeScript and Vite, and I’m having trouble with the build process. I used the built-in template from Electron Forge with Vite and TypeScript for my project setup.

In development mode, everything works fine. All my HTML files and scripts for them are served through my `src/views/` folder where they are stored. So in development mode I can access them through this path `${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL}/src/views/index.html.` However, when I try to build for production, I run into issues.

Here’s the code I’m using to load my index.html file in my `/src/windows/mainWindow.ts`:

```js
if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
  this.loadURL(`${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL}/src/views/index.html`);
} else {
  this.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../src/views/index.html"));
}
```

Here’s my `vite.main.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    browserField: false,
    mainFields: ["module", "jsnext:main", "jsnext"],
  },
});
```

When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

```bash
$ npm run make

> my-new-app@1.0.0 make
> electron-forge make

✔ Checking your system
✔ Loading configuration
✔ Loading configuration
✔ Resolving make targets
  › Making for the following targets: squirrel
✔ Loading configuration
✔ Resolving make targets
  › Making for the following targets: squirrel
❯ Running package command
  ✔ Preparing to package application
  ❯ Running packaging hooks
    ✔ Running generateAssets hook
    ❯ Running prePackage hook
      ✖ [plugin-vite] Building vite bundles
        › Could not resolve entry module "index.html".
  ◼ Packaging application
  ◼ Running postPackage hook
◼ Running preMake hook
◼ Making distributables
◼ Running postMake hook

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "index.html".
at error (file:///F:/Project/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///F:/Project/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24876:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

It seems like it cannot find my index.html file and others during the build process. I’m not sure how to configure my project so that these files are included in the build. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my project structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxtLv.png)

I tried to load my HTML files using different paths. Here’s the code I used:

```js
if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
  this.loadURL(`${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL}/src/views/inputWindow.html`);
} else {
  this.loadFile(join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
}
```

I expected this code to correctly load my HTML files both in development mode (served from the Vite dev server) and in production mode (served from the built files). However, this didn’t work as expected.